# Shared Library/DLL: Boundary Classes and new/delete Operators in Source (Translation Unit)/Header

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, new-operator, delete-operator

I know related questions have been asked many times already, but I couldn't find any trace of one particular detail that bothers me. What if there is the following class on shared library/DLL boundary:

`Class.hpp`:

```
class EXPORT Class {
  Object* New() {
    return new Object;
  }

  void Delete(Object* object);
};
```

`Class.cpp`:

```
void Class::Delete(Object* object) {
  delete object;
}
```

Or vice versa:

`Class.hpp`:

```
class EXPORT Class {
  Object* New();

  void Delete(Object* object) {
    delete object;
  }
};
```

`Class.cpp`:

```
Object* Class::New() {
  return new Object;
}
```

Supposing that `Class.hpp` is included in other 3rd party project to use the respective shared library/DLL, the methods which are not defined in translation units (`Class.cpp` in this toy example) will be built on the client side. Does that imply that the runtimes used for `new`/`delete` pairs (in both examples) can really differ, i.e. are we subject to crash?

If not, then what if these (header-defined) methods were also defined as `inline`? What if they were templated, i.e. we had no choice but to define them in headers? E.g.:

```
class EXPORT Class {
  template <class T>
  T* New() {
    return new T;
  }

  void Delete(void* object);
};
```

To summarize, should shared library/DLL boundary classes contain `new`/`delete` pairs either in the respective translation units (sources) or headers, but not mixed?

For example, consider the following boundary class:

```
template <class T>
class Class {
public:
  Class(T* p)
    : _p(p)
  {}

  ~Class()
  { if (_p) { delete _p; } }

private:
  T* _p;
};
```

There could be a situation when one of shared library/DLL translation units does:

```
Class<X> c(new X);
```

Are we subject to crash when `c` goes out of scope and some 3rd party project uses our shared library/DLL? If yes, then, would:

`Class.hpp`:

```
void Delete(void* p);

template <class T>
class Class {
  ...

  ~Class()
  { if (_p) { _p->~T(); Delete(_p); } }

  ...
};
```

`Class.cpp`:

```
void Delete(void* p) {
  delete p;
}
```

be a good solution in this case? Any other elegant suggestions? Keep in mind, I can't use 3rd party/standard smart pointers here.

Comment: The answers are all implementation specific. If your compiler is MSVC for example, plausible since you talk of DLLs, then you need to make sure that all code uses the same runtime.

Comment: @David: I have a feeling that it could potentially happen in any environment, not only Windows. Aren't shared libraries linked against different `libc` runtimes subject to the same issue?

Comment: Yes of course. But the rules are all implementation specific. Which makes this question essentially unanswerable. Do you really want me to write an answer that says merely, "it depends on your implementation".

Comment: @David: Basically, could you tell me whether the last solution is inherently bulletproof or not?

Comment: No, that's hopeless. You are pass a `void*` to delete. So it might be able to deallocate the memory, but it is not able to run a destructor.

Comment: @David: I've updated it. So what if I manually call destructor prior calling `Delete`?

Comment: Manually call the destructor? I don't think so. Why are you fighting against the system?

Comment: @David: I'm just trying to find a solution which lets me to ensure that the same `new`/`delete` are called for an object.

Comment: It's still implementation specific. There is no single solution.